# What operations are thread-safe on std::map?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary, std

Suppose I have:

```
stl::map<std::string, Foo> myMap;
```

is the following function thread safe?

```
myMap["xyz"] ?
```

I.e. I want to have this giant read-only map that is shared among many threads; but I don't know if even searching it is thread safe.

---

Everything is written to once first.

Then after that, multiple threads read from it.

I'm trying to avoid locks to make this as faast as possible. (yaya possible premature optimization I know)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In theory no STL containers are threadsafe. In practice reading is safe if the container is not being concurrently modified.  ie the standard makes no specifications about threads. The next version of the standard will and IIUC it will then guarantee safe readonly behaviour.

If you are really concerned, use a sorted array with binary search.

Answer (score 17):

C++11 requires that all member functions declared as `const` are thread-safe for multiple readers.

Calling `myMap["xyz"]` is not thread-safe, as `std::map::operator[]` isn't declared as `const`.
Calling `myMap.at("xyz")` is thread-safe though, as `std::map::at` is declared as `const`.

Answer (score 6):

At least in Microsoft's implementation, reading from containers is thread-safe ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9ceah3b(VS.80).aspx)).

However, `std::map::operator[]` can modify data and is not declared `const`. You should instead use `std::map::find`, which is `const`, to get a `const_iterator` and dereference it.

Comment: in order for there to be anything in a container, it needs to be written to. Hence the thread safety concern...

Comment: The questions specifies that we are looking at a read-only map. I assume this means it is filled completely in one thread before being read from multiple threads.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, read-only data structures and functions do not require any locks for thread-safety. It is inherently thread-safe. There are **no data races** on concurrent memory reads. However, you must guarantee safe initializations by only a single thread.

As Max S. pointed out, mostly implementation of reading an element in map like `myMap["xyz"]` would have no write operations. If so, then it is safe. But, once again, you must guarantee there is no thread which modifies the structure except the initialization phase.

Answer (score 1):

STL collections aren't threadsafe, but it's fairly simple to add thread safety to one.

Your best bet is create a threadsafe wrapper around the collection in question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but as all existing answers -and in particular the accepted one- are incorrect, I am adding another one (sorry, not enough rep for comments).

Because the OP explicitly mentions a read-only access (_"giant read-only map"), the `[]` operator should actually not be used since it can result in an insert. The `at` or `find` methods are suitable alternatives.

Some non-const functions are considered `const` in the context of thread-safety. `at` and `find` are such pseudo-const functions (this is explained very nicely in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15067564/11648131). More details are available from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) as well under the "thread-safety" section. And finally and see [C++11 standard 23.2.2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/container.requirements.dataraces) for the official list).

As long as only `const` operations are used on the container the execution is thread-safe. As you initialize the huge map once (and do not modify it afterwards) before accessing it read-only from other threads, you are safe!

Comment: `map::operator[]` can insert new elements in the map, so it is not thread-safe, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: @Fedor I agree and I will update my answer to remove the ambiguity: the OP explicitly mentioned a const access (_"giant **read-only** map"_), and in that context I see the `[]` operator as equivalent to the `at` method, which is considered const.

Comment: update of previos comment: @Fedor thank you, I agree and I will update my answer to remove the ambiguity: the OP explicitly mentioned a const access (_"giant **read-only** map"_), but I implicitly used that context to downgrade the `[]` operation to an `at` method call, which is thread-safe. In fact, considering the OP's intention `at` or `find` should be used instead of `[]` to ensure that the map is not modified.