# Need I really use another template in this case

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, reference, forwarding-reference

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class ThreadSafeMap
{
    std::mutex m_;
    std::map<Key, Value> c_;

public:
    Value get(Key const& k) {
        std::unique_lock<decltype(m_)> lock(m_);
        return c_[k]; // Return a copy.
    }

    template<class Value2>
    void set(Key const& k, Value2&& v) {
        std::unique_lock<decltype(m_)> lock(m_);
        c_[k] = std::forward<Value2>(v);
    }
};
```

[Thread safe std::map: Locking the entire map and individual values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987641/thread-safe-stdmap-locking-the-entire-map-and-individual-values)

I just read the link above and found the piece of code. It looks great with it to make a thread-safe map. I understand that in the function `set`, we used the reference collapsing rules on the second parameter `v`. But I don't understand why we need import another `template<class Value2>`, why can't we simply use the existing template `class Value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is supposed to be declared as [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), which only works with templates. Then we need make `set` itself template.

(emphasis mine)

> Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve the value category of a function argument, making it possible to *forward* it by means of [std::forward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). Forwarding references are either:
>
> 1. function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-unqualified **type template parameter of that same function template**:

If we declare `set` as a non-template as:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class ThreadSafeMap
{
    ...

    // non-template member function
    void set(Key const& k, Value&& v) {
        std::unique_lock<decltype(m_)> lock(m_);
        c_[k] = std::forward<Value2>(v);
    }
};
```

`v` will be just an rvalue-reference.

Comment: I think their asking why not use the outer template, on the class, i.e. use `value` template value. That also seems to be "working with templates".

Comment: Thanks, but not for me at least - you could write *`v2` will be an rvalue-reference* and it will not be clear which is right. In essence, I think you need to make the distinction of what happens in both cases (which are valid in the sense they are allowed by the language), perhaps with a differentiating usage example.

Comment: TBH I thought allowing `Value2` was just for more flexibility in auto-casting rules and the like, not rvalue-lvalue stuff.

Comment: I guess this could be a "What is a forwarding reference" question, since your answer will only be clear to language (semi) experts., I think

Comment: Anyway, upvoted for being the best kind of correct, but I'm not sure this is enough for OP.

Comment: @kabanus Hmm, I'm not sure what OP's confusing, is it why forwarding reference should be used, or OP knows it should be forwarding reference but why need import another `template<class Value2>`. Anyway I tried to add both aspects.