# Can I use std::map in parallel when I don't add/remove keys?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program which uses a lot of `std::map` structures. Now I want to use them with with multiple threads and assume that inserting or deleting keys will potentially alter the whole data structure and break it in parallel. But when I do not add new keys, it should be fine, right?

The following program shows what I want to do:

```cpp
#include <omp.h>                                                                

#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <map>                                                                  

int main(int const argc, char const *const *const argv) {                          
  // Take a map and allocate the elements, but not fill them at this point.        
  std::map<int, int> map;                                                          
  int size = 10000;                                                                
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {                                                 
    map[i];                                                                        
  }                                                                                

  // Go through the elements in parallel and write to them, but not create any  
  // new elements. Therefore there should not be any allocations and it should  
  // be thread-safe.                                                               
#pragma omp parallel                                                               
  {                                                                                
    int const me = omp_get_thread_num();                                           
#pragma omp for                                                                    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {                                               
      map[i] = me;                                                                 
    }                                                                              
  }                                                                                

  // Now all threads access all the elements of the map, but as the map is not  
  // changed any more, nothing bad should happen.                               
#pragma omp parallel                                                               
  {                                                                                
    int const me = omp_get_thread_num();                                           
    int self = 0;                                                                  

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {                                               
      if (map[i] == me) {                                                          
        ++self;                                                                    
      }                                                                            
    }                                                                              

#pragma omp critical(cout)                                                         
    std::cout << "Thread " << me << " found " << self << " entries.\n";            
  }                                                                                
}
```

Then I compile it with the following:

```
$ g++ -fopenmp -O3 -Wall -Wpedantic -g -fsanitize=address -o concurrent-map concurrent-map.cpp
```

This seems to work just fine with four threads. If I comment out the first for loop and let the threads populate the map, it crashes with segmentation faults, as I expect.

Of course I cannot prove that `std::map` is thread-safe in the way I think this way, but it at least does not prove the negative. Can I use the `std::map` in this fashion in parallel?

Comment: If performance is important, you almost always would want to use `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: This may be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067160/stdmap-thread-safety. I feel that what you are doing is not thread safe.

Comment: `operator[]` is not `const` for `std::map`, so implementation is allowed to be non-threadsafe. Better alternative is to use `map.find(i)->second`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using `map[i]` specifically is thread safe for all C++ implementations, even if it is not inserting a new element. The standard does not require `operator[]` to be data race free for associative containers:

Section [[container.requirement.dataraces]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/containers#container.requirements.dataraces-1) of the C++17 standard draft contains a list of functions that should not cause data races, even though they are not `const`. The list includes `find` and `at`, but not `operator[]`.

Therefore you need to use `find` or `at` instead of `operator[]`. A particular implementation may give stronger guarantees and that may be likely if `map[i]` is not inserting a new element, but you would need to check that with your compiler/standard library documentation.

Aside from that, access, even modifying, to different elements of a container is always fine (except for `vector<bool>`), see the next paragraph in the standard.

Comment: Since this code is running on various machines (amd64, ppc) with various compilers (GCC, LLVM, Intel C++), it likely is better to use `at` instead of `operator[]`. The additional range checking should not be that expensive and actually help to fortify the code against dumb mistakes.

Comment: @MartinUeding I don't know how openmp  handles exceptions uncaught in a parallel block, so you might want to read up on that first. My guess is that it is simply not allowed leading to a call to std::terminate or UB. I suppose you need to add a `catch` inside the parallel block to be caught by the throwing thread.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: 
There is no standard guarantee it will work properly since `operator[]` is not guaranteed to not modify the structure. Instead `at()` or `find()` would be better choices.

<strike>As far as I understand C++ standard and OpenMP docs - this is safe. Firstly, as long as you don't make operations modifying iterators the parallel modification should be fine.</strike>

Second question is if the data written in different threads will be visible in other threads. Luckily OpenMP has pretty good documentation which states that memory sync happens implicitly:

> At exit from the task region of each implicit task;